# How does Halosulfuron-methyl kill nutsedge, while leaving lawn grass and most weeds undamaged?

Tags: botany, toxicology

I use [Halosulfuron-methyl](http://www.sedgehammer.com/sedgehammer-plus.html) to control yellow and purple nutsedge in lawns. This chemical acts by interfering with the acetolactate synthase enzyme, which quickly slows cell division, and growth at all points.

[image]

How does this work without also interfering with enzymes in the lawn grass?

Comment: http://hortsci.ashspublications.org/content/30/2/285.full.pdf

Comment: @DevashishDas The paper does not seem to be relevant in answering this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Halosulfuron-methyl is a member of the family of sulfonylurea herbicides. [Brown (2006)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ps.2780290304/abstract) mentions in his abstract the following, and I quote:

> This class of herbicides acts through inhibition of acetolactate synthase [...], thereby blocking the biosynthesis of the branched-chain amino acids valine, leucine and isoleucine. This inhibition leads to the rapid cessation of plant cell division and growth. [...] **Crop selectivity results from rapid metabolic inactivation of the herbicide in the tolerant crop.** Under growth-room conditions, metabolic half-lives in tolerant crop plants range from 1–5 h, while sensitive plant species metabolize these herbicides much more slowly, with half-lives > 20 h. Pathways by which sulfonylurea herbicides are inactivated among these plants include aryl and aliphatic hydroxylation followed by glucose conjugation, sulfonylurea bridge hydrolysis and sulfonamide bond cleavage, oxidative O-demethylation and direct conjugation with (homo)glutathione.

Hence, metabolic inactivation activity differs between susceptible and insusceptible species. To get to your question: this means that the **enzymes in lawn grass are also inhibited**, but to a lesser extent, as the herbicide is metabolized and inactivated more rapidly in grasses.

<sup>**Reference**</sup>
<sup>[Brown, Pesticide Science 2006;29:241–378](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ps.2780290304/abstract)</sup>